# How to get duration dates between two dates?(php)

Tags: php, mysql

How to get duration dates between two dates in php?
(year/month/day)! How to?

One date is in mysql database and other one is today!!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the php date_diff() function 
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date-diff.php